# Create a notification with selectable text?

Tags: notifications, screenshot

I want to be able to take a screenshot and receive a notification to the exact path where its stored so I can copy paste the path to open the file or move it or whatever.

I've looked into send-notify but I'm not sure if I can use this to create selectable text. It seems to just disappear when I click the notification.

Are there any tools out there that can do this?

I'm running on Arch btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can take screenshots directly into your clipboard with [maim](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/taking_a_screenshot#maim):

```
maim | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
```

or if you want saved file and the filename on your clipboard, then:

```
fn=/tmp/shot-$(date +%F_%T).png ; maim "$fn"; echo "$fn" | xclip
```